# Pandas ewm correlation - not rolling

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
             a   b   c
2023-01-01  35  34  17
2023-01-02  85  54  31
2023-01-03  33   8  27
2023-01-04  95   9  45
2023-01-05  71  98   7
```

I want to calculate today's (2023-01-05) EWM correlations between the 3 series.

I tried

```
correls = data.ewm(alpha=0.01, adjust=True).corr(method='pearson')
```

and it produced rolling correlations (calculated on all dates):

```
                     a         b         c
2023-01-01 a       NaN       NaN       NaN
           b       NaN       NaN       NaN
           c       NaN       NaN       NaN
2023-01-02 a  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
           b  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
           c  1.000000  1.000000  1.000000
2023-01-03 a  1.000000  0.845674  0.694635
           b  0.845674  1.000000  0.203512
           c  0.694635  0.203512  1.000000
2023-01-04 a  1.000000  0.177224  0.842738
           b  0.177224  1.000000 -0.362909
           c  0.842738 -0.362909  1.000000
2023-01-05 a  1.000000  0.209568  0.478477
           b  0.209568  1.000000 -0.748170
           c  0.478477 -0.748170  1.000000
```

I know I can now slice the correls dataframe to get only the latest correlations. The problem is the real "data" dataframe is very large and computing rolling correlations takes a lot of time. Since I only need today's correlations, how can I avoid EWN.corr function calculating rolling correlations in the first place?

To be clear, I'm looking for a fast way to get the following output:

```
          a         b         c
a  1.000000  0.209568  0.478477
b  0.209568  1.000000 -0.748170
c  0.478477 -0.748170  1.000000
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do so without computing it all, after all the `ewm` function needs the previous data in order to compute the new data

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef. You can slice the dataframe and not compute the EWMA from the start of history if the OP wants the correlation of the last day of his dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC to compute the EWMA, you need past data but you needn't all values because oldest values are not really significant. I think you need about 300 days of history to compute a good correlation.

Why 300 days ? The coefficients are computed with `wt = (1 - alpha)^t` so the 300th have a weight of 0.0495 in the moving average:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
w = (1 - 0.01)**np.arange(365*2)
cs = np.cumsum(w)
ax1.plot(w, label='Coefficient')
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(cs, 'k', label='Cumulative sum')
ax1.set_title(r'Weights for $\alpha=0.01$')
ax1.set_ylabel('Weight in EWMA')
ax1.set_xlabel('Days')
ax1.axvline(0, c='r', ls='--', lw=0.5)
ax1.axhline(0.05, c='g', ls='--', lw=0.5)
ax1.axvline(300, c='g', ls='--', lw=0.5)
ax1.text(300, 0.08, 'Weights > 0.05')
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
# For hist=300 days
>>> w[300], cs[300]
(0.04904089407128572, 95.14495148694262)

# For hist=500 days, a better accuracy and a cumsum ~= 100)
>>> w[500], cs[500]
(0.006570483042414603, 99.34952217880091)
```

How to use it:

```
hist = 300
df.iloc[hist:].ewm(alpha=0.5, adjust=True).corr().loc[df.index[-1]]
```

**Note**: more your alpha is small, more your need a larger history.